# match if a json in containing another json with karate

Tags: karate

i have to verify if a json contain at last another json, like the this test:

```html
def subset = { bar: { foo: 'xxx' }} 
def superset = { bar: { foo: 'xxx', baz: 'yyy' }} 
match superset contains subset
```

it's correct if fails as follow?

`path: $.bar, actual: {foo=xxx, baz=yyy}, expected: {foo=xxx}, reason: actual value has 1 more key(s) than expected: {baz=yyy}`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def part = { foo: 'xxx' } 
* def superset = { bar: { foo: 'xxx', baz: 'yyy' } } 
* match superset == { bar: '#(^part)' }
```

Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#contains-short-cuts

Comment: Thanks @peter, but there is a way without re-write the outer json? I have to verify if a rest response contains the request, and the request has unpredictable parts.

In any case, the `match` i wrote in original post, is correct that fails?

Comment: Ok, my approach was wrong :)
But at last, i was especting that `cointains` to be applied also at nested json parts and the first match to succede